# Who chatted with you the most app on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chat

There is an app on facebook which can tell an user who he has chatted with the most. How is it possible to access the number of messages via the facebook graph api?

Comment: have you tried looking here https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: Yes. I have but I am not sure how to work with the inbox

Comment: Well show us what you've tried. Is this using php, the js-sdk or a native sdk for ios or android as well?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Issue resolved

I implemented the "SELECT message_count FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0" in FQL

My app is working now.